# Not a manifold: $x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0$

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x,y) = x^3+y^3-3xy$, then $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) = 0 \}$ is not a $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

I have two questions.

1) The given solution merely states that $M$ is defined as set of roots of a $C^{\infty}$-function, so it suffices to check that $f$ does not have full rank in $(0,0)$.

However, I only know that characterization that "some $M$ is a manifold if and only if there **exists** such $f$ ...". So is it possibly true that a stronger result holds? Something in the spirit of

*"Let $M$ be locally defined as the roots of a $C^1$ function. If it does not have full rank in $p \in M$, then $M$ is not a manifold."?*

2) How would you show it otherwise? I'd reckon you could argue that the number of connected components doesn't match with those of some interval in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Though, I'm not too sure if it's easy to prove that $M$ looks like that.

Comment: Look at [this.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E3%2By%5E3%E2%88%923xy%3D0) Seems like you can prove this by considering a neighborhood around the origin.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in 2). Admittingly, I didn't formulate it very well - I want to remove the origin, then the neighborhood falls into 4 pieces. Those would be too many connected components.

Comment: The codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, fixed the typo; thank you.